# Автоподстановка для ДОКУМЕНТООБОРОТА 1С

Tags: 1с

Подскажите пожалуйста. 
Нужна автоподстановка для документооборота.

Чтобы, когда сотрудник создавал документ на согласование, он отправлялся не его руководителю, а вышестоящему.*(То есть руководителю руководителя)* 
Может кто подсказать ?)
Или хотя бы подсказать где искать ответы.
Заранее спасибо!

**Вот код:**

```
Результат = Справочники.Сотрудники.ПустаяСсылка();
Если ДелопроизводствоКлиентСервер.ЭтоДокумент(Объект.Ссылка) Тогда
    ПараметрыАлгоритма = Новый Структура("Сотрудник", Объект.Подготовил); 
    Результат = Справочники.Алгоритмы.Вызвать("НепосредственныйРуководительСотрудника", ПараметрыАлгоритма);
КонецЕсли;
```

Подскажите пожалуйста!
Знаю, что проще по другому, но требуется именно так.

Comment: Укажите версию Документооборота в вопросе; Обычно такой сценарий является - ошибкой; Тем не менее, такую настройку можно сделать - без программирования* прямо в программе; Для этого настройте маршрут согласования; Либо настройте делегирование от Начальника -> Вышестоящему начальнику (такой сценарий обычно используется когда Начальник уходит в отпуск) Более подробно только после указания версии Документооборота;

Comment: Документооборот КОРП, редакция 3.0 (3.0.10.20)